# How do I build a custom backend for firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, progressive-web-apps

1. How do I do my business logic on server-side on firebase?
2. Will the web app still have the benefits of progressive web app if I do this?

***Reason to do this:*** Anybody can run Javascript code on your website if the person knows how to use the developer tools available in modern browsers.

Is firebase Queue (NodeJS on AWS) the way? I am a noob to all this.

Comment: It looks like you also perhaps answered this question on Quora, which is definitely a better forum for this kind of question: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-build-a-custom-backend-for-firebase/answer/Doug-Stevenson-1

Answer (score 1):

You need to write more of your business logic on font-side than traditional way. To make it safe, you need to write access rules carefully on firebase console.
And it's not enough, you also need a server-side, nodejs is a good choice, there are many useful library, such as firebase, firebase-queue, firebase-admin. You can deploy these servers on the google cloud with docker.